# ansible & bash deployment on remote tomcat server

Tags: bash, tomcat, deployment, ansible

I have written an ansible script to execute a bash scipt on remote server.
When I am running the same bash script directly on node, Its working fine.
Through ansible its not working properly and return without any error.

Scenario: 1. kill tomcat 2.deploy the war file 3.start tomcat

This scenario perfectly works while executing directly on remote node. 
Through ansible tomcat is getting killed but deploy and start is not working.

Can anyone guide please.

Comment: I feel its due to user issue. for ssh am using root once ssh happened it will sudo to other user and deploy the script.

Comment: fatal: [x.x.x.x]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to x.x.x.x closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "sudo: a password is required\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

Comment: Thanks yash.

already given sudoers access to the newuser and am getting another error where i cannot find the root cause.

ERROR:
fatal: [x.x.x.x]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to x.x.x.x closed.\r\n",
    "unreachable": true
}
        to retry, use: --limit @/tmp/deployment:.retry

Comment: PART1:
#ansible script to execute a bash script to deploy


---
- hosts: webservers
  remote_user: newuser
  #sudo: yes
  become: true
  tasks:
   - name: Execute deployment script
     command: sh /tmp/deployment.sh {{version}}
  
  
PART2:
deployment script has 3 steps
1. stop tomcat
2. download and deploy war
3. stop tomcat

PART3:
through ansible while calling the bash script to execute on remote node.
Step 1 (stop tomcat) is working fine.
Step 2 & 3 not happening.

Comment: Note: tomcat service should run on newuser whereelse ssh(22) on remote node can be done via both newuser & root

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the user. Seems like the user is not added in the sudoers file.

Also please make a practice to update the question with as much info as possible. For eg playbook code error using the proper syntax that SO supports

Cheers,
Yash